# Change links before or when clicked? GA Cross-domain tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain

I have a situation where I have to manually decorate a specific link across my entire website with the Google Analytics linkerParam.

This is to pass the GA client ID from my main site over to my ecommerce site in order to maintain the session.

Normally this would occur automatically through the auto linker settings but there is a server-side redirect page that sits between my site and the ecommerce site.

That redirect page would pass along the GA client ID but it's never given a chance because it's a page on my domain and not the external domain. Auto linker won't work in that situation which is why I need to manually do it myself.

The solution that I've been given basically adds a javascript addEventListener to each link to the redirect page.

That solution does work.

Is it better to use the addEventListener for when people actually click on the specific link to only then decorate that link with the linkerParam?

Or is it better to simply modify each link when the page initially loads?

Thanks

Comment: Try to get the UserId from the ga object on your target site. It should be the same as on the origin site if both sites are linked with autolink

Comment: I don't have much control over the target site. This is why I am trying to decorate the URL before I send people to the target site.

Comment: Oh sorry. I missed the part that autolink doesn't work for you and you also have found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my custom linkers I decorate the link only after is has been clicked. My reasons (which you may or may not find convincing) are:

- if a user hovers over a link I do not want him to see an attached client id
- since search engines now execute javascript they might index decorated links
- I can decorate links only after they are actually on the page  (but I can attach a callback function to links that are created after the fact), so if a user leaves before DOM ready the link is not decorated
- On a page with lot's of links decorating all of them actually takes some time and performance for something that I do not really need (after all I only need the clicked link decorated)

As to Ithans comment above (where I think he referred to the DOM rather than the sinister sounding "doom"), since the user leaves the page in any case after clicking the link (you would not decorate in-page linking), so multiple DOM operations are not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change all the links when the page load

something like

```
    var linksToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.theLinkClass');

   for (var item of linksToChange ) {
     item.href= "http://google.es";
   };
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. I know how to do this. I am wondering which is better? When someone clicks (addEventListener ) or modifying the href at the page load?

Comment: Oh sorry, the best way is modify each link when the page loads, so you don't have to modify the doom each time the event its called